# nvim autocomplete menu, arrow selection. Invert left/right - up/down functions

Tags: vim, selection, neovim

When trying to select from a list, see image below, the left/right and up/down arrows are acting unintuitve (for me): The left/right move the selection up and down, while the down arrows selects it, the up arrow selects the item above the marked one.

I know the CTRL-N/P but how can I use the arrows in a more intuitive way? Is there a setting I can change?
A remap I can define?

Thanks all..

[image]

Comment: I have the same question. Did you manage to find a solution in the meantime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I was asked, this is what I did:

```
set wildcharm=<C-Z>
cnoremap <expr> <up> wildmenumode() ? "\<left>" : "\<up>"
cnoremap <expr> <down> wildmenumode() ? "\<right>" : "\<down>"
cnoremap <expr> <left> wildmenumode() ? "\<up>" : "\<left>"
cnoremap <expr> <right> wildmenumode() ? " \<bs>\<C-Z>" : "\<right>"
```

I stole it from someone, don't remember where. But all credit to whoever made it (wasn't me).

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
set wildcharm=<C-Z>
let edit_re = 'e\%[dit] '
cnoremap <expr> <up> getcmdline() =~# edit_re && wildmenumode() ? "\<left>" : "\<up>"
cnoremap <expr> <down> getcmdline() =~# edit_re && wildmenumode() ? "\<right>" : "\<down>"
cnoremap <expr> <left> getcmdline() =~# edit_re && wildmenumode() ? "\<up>" : "\<left>"
cnoremap <expr> <right> getcmdline() =~# edit_re && wildmenumode() ? " \<bs>\<C-Z>" : "\<right>"
```

See explanation here:
https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/22627/switching-arrow-key-mappings-for-wildmenu-tab-completion